# I want MAC address of devices which are connected to same wifi. So, I tried this code bt error I'am getting is 'storage size of ifr is not known'

Tags: c

```
int getMACAddress(int iNetType, char chMAC[6]) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sock;
    char *ifname=NULL;

 if (!iNetType) {
   ifname="eth0"; /* Ethernet */
} 
 else {
   ifname="wlan0"; /* Wifi */
}

sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
strcpy( ifr.ifr_name, ifname );

ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
  if (ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &amp;ifr ) &lt; 0) {
  return -1;
}

memcpy(chMAC, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6)
close(sock);
return 0;
}
```

This is the code to get MAC address of devices. What could be the problem? I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you add [required headers](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html)

Comment: Hi Shrija, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Even if you get it to compile, it wouldn't do what you want - It will only return *your own interface's* hardware address and not those of "connected to the same WiFi".

Comment: ok. Then how can I get the MAC address of connected devices? And thanks for the information tofro.

Comment: No LPs. I haven't added any headers.